# Optimizing SQLAlchemy Relationships for a Three-Table Model: Business, Reviews, and ReviewedBusiness

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm working with a database that involves three tables: Business, Reviews, and ReviewedBusiness. The Business table stores businesses registered by their owners, the ReviewedBusiness table contains businesses registered by users who are not the owners and includes reviews, and the Reviews table holds reviews that can be associated with either a Business or a ReviewedBusiness.

Here is my current SQLAlchemy implementation:

**Review Table**

```
class Review(Base):
    __tablename__ = "reviews"
    id = Column(String(36), primary_key=True, default=gen_uuid)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now())

    entity_type = Column(String(20), nullable=False)

    @declared_attr
    def business_id(cls):
        return Column(String(36), ForeignKey("businesses.id"), nullable=True)

    @declared_attr
    def reviewed_business_id(cls):
        return Column(String(36), ForeignKey("reviewed_businesses.id"), nullable=True)

    user = relationship(
        "User",
        back_populates="reviews",
        primaryjoin="foreign(Review.user_id) == User.id",
    )

    # Move the relationship definitions to the end
    business = relationship(
        "Business",
        back_populates="reviews",
        primaryjoin="and_(Review.business_id == Business.id, Review.entity_type == 'business')",
    )

    reviewed_businesses = relationship(
        "ReviewedBusiness",
        back_populates="reviews",
        primaryjoin="and_(Review.reviewed_business_id == ReviewedBusiness.id, Review.entity_type == 'reviewed_business')",
    )
```

**ReviewedBusiness**

```
class ReviewedBusiness(Base):
    __tablename__ = "reviewed_businesses"
    id = mapped_column(String(255), primary_key=True, default=str(gen_uuid))
    created_at = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now())

    user = relationship(
        "User",
        back_populates="reviewed_businesses",
        primaryjoin="foreign(ReviewedBusiness.user_id) == User.id",
    )
    reviews = relationship(
        "Review",
        back_populates="reviewed_businesses",
        primaryjoin="ReviewedBusiness.id == foreign(Review.business_id)",
    )
```

**Business Table**

```
class Business(Base):
    __tablename__ = "businesses"
    id = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=gen_uuid)
    created_at = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now())

    user = relationship(
        "User",
        back_populates="businesses",
        primaryjoin="foreign(Business.user_id) == User.id",
    )
    reviews = relationship(
        "Review",
        back_populates="business",
        primaryjoin="Business.id == foreign(Review.business_id)",
    )
```

I would like to optimize the relationships between these tables and explore potential improvements. The current implementation seems to be encountering issues, and I believe there might be better ways to structure these relationships. Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Additional context: I'm using SQLAlchemy and MySQL for this project.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what the issues are?  Performance?  Complexity of queries?